# Normalizer of Levi subgroup

Tags: group-theory

So for the linear algebraic group $G = SL_3(K)$ where K is algebraically closed. I know there is a Levi subgroup $L$ isomorphic to $ GL_2(K)$ which is a 4-dimensional reductive subgroup. How to find the normalizer of $L$ in $G$. I got stuck here for a while now. I know the forms the parabolic and Levi subgroups take. But direct calculation got me nowhere. Thx.